# PostgreSQL Install Error: Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Failed to start the database server

Tags: windows, postgresql

Most are getting errors regarding clusters, but I'm getting an error beside it.

Any solutions my colleagues? I've tried installing 2 ways:

- Via Chocolatey Pkg Manager: I've uninstalled and reinstalled different versions 10 and 12 to no avail. I can't create a new user to install it from as I'm on a corporate laptop. Installation is stuck at `Installing PostgreSQL1X...`.
- Via .exe but error message mentioned in title pops up at the end of the installation.

What other ways are there?